# Highcharts dynamically add a new series in a chart with different plot options

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

please have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sqp_124/54zvqubk/3/

I just want to add new series data to a chart which contains already one or more series. Thereby I do not want to change the current series by adding a new series.

However the new series should have different plot options. In the code especially doing things with the marker do not have any effect....:

```js
  plotOptions: {
   series: {
    marker: {
     fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
     lineWidth: 10,
     lineColor: null 
    }
   }
  }
```

How is it possible to dynamically add a new series in a given chart and define specific plot options for that series?

In the end actually I would like to add 3 points in my current chart and fill them therefore I need to change plot options and I think I have to do something with an area which I have to fill.

Comment: Use the force Luke...errr I mean the api: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart Take a look at the addSeries method under Chart

Comment: I already looked at this one here: addSeries (Object options, [Boolean redraw], [Mixed animation]) in the api but I just do not get it how it works... cause actually I am using that in my fiddle but nothing happens or?

Comment: In the APi, there is an example how you can add series. In object options specify all the options, you want the series to have - data, marker optioins, color, etc. http://jsfiddle.net/t3soa82h/